# Getting the content of div's with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i have several divs like this one, i create them with ajax

```
.done(function( response ) {
    $("#stores").html('');
    var iterator = response.retailer;
    for (var i=0;i<iterator.length;i++){
    $("#stores").html($("#stores").html()+
    "<div id="+response.retailer[i].id+" class='panel panel-default '>"+
    "<div class='panel-body'>"+
    "<p> Name: "+response.retailer[i].name+"<p>"+
    "<p> Address: "+response.retailer[i].address+"<p>"+                
    " <button id='AddAndSave' class='btn btn-success col-md-offset-10'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button>"+
    "</div>"+
    "</div>");
    }
})
```

if you see, in the div i have a button, this button when i click it, i want to take all the content of that div and save it in variables, how exactly i can do this? any reference?

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console ?

Comment: Nope, i just want to know if anyone can help me with an idea

Comment: ID need to be unique, so change the `id='AddAndSave'` into a class.

Comment: you're printing the same id `AddAndSave` <iterator.length> times

Comment: This is bad `$("#stores").html($("#stores").html()+` just use `append()`. Even better, build a string and append it at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, **don't use an ID on that button**, you are surely gonna have more than one. So, **use a class instead** :

```
.done(function( response ) {
    $("#stores").html('');
    var iterator = response.retailer;
    for (var i=0;i<iterator.length;i++){
    $("#stores").append("<div id="+response.retailer[i].id+" class='panel panel-default '>"+
    "<div class='panel-body'>"+
    "<p> Name: "+response.retailer[i].name+"<p>"+
    "<p> Address: "+response.retailer[i].address+"<p>"+                
    " <button class='AddAndSave btn btn-success col-md-offset-10'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button>"+
    "</div>"+
    "</div>");
    }
})
```

Then, right now, you can't attach event to that element as it's created after `$(document).ready();`, **you need to delegate that event to the document itself** (or any "static" parent) :

```
$(document).on('click', '.AddAndSave', function(){
  // Do some stuff on click on .AddAndSave
});
```

*Also, note that I replaced your html() method by append() method : it surely will be more efficient.*